# Time stamp conversion and deltatime with a decimal error

Tags: python, csv, decimal, timedelta

We are working with a timestamp column in a CSV file and are running into an error because the CSV timestamp is formatted like this: 30:50.0 where we are fairly sure that its hours and minutes. With a decimal for seconds, however every decimal is 0. We are using this code to read and grab the times:

```
fmt = "%H:%M.0"
```

However, it returns this error:
ValueError: time data '30:50.0' does not match format '%H:%M.0'
similar error returned for using: '%H:%M.%S'
finally when just '%H:%M is used we get this error:
unconverted data remains: .0
We are out of ideas on how to either edit or otherwise read the time code. without manually editing the CSV file.

```
# Import moduels for use
from datetime import datetime as dt
import itertools

# Creating a function that will get the total difference in time between each point
def compute_delta_time(timelist):
    timetotal = []
    a, b = itertools.tee(timelist)
    next(b, None)
    fmt = "%H:%M.0"
    for start, end in itertools.izip(a,b):  
        timetotal.append((dt.strptime(end, fmt) - dt.strptime(start, fmt)).total_seconds())
    return timetotal
```

Here is our entire function.

Answer (score 1):

You could brute force it:

```
>>> x="30:50.0"
>>> h,mm=x.split(":")
>>> m,s=mm.split(".")
>>> int(h)
30
>>> int(m)
50
>>> int(s)
0
```

It's ugly, but workable.

Also, I suggest you add the tag "python" to your post.

Answer (score 0):

`%H` must be in 0..23 range. You could parse the duration string manually as [@PfunnyGuy suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36941089/4279):

```
def to_seconds(duration_string):
    """'30:50.0' -> 111000"""
    hm, dot, seconds = duration_string.partition('.')
    hours, minutes = map(int, hm.split(':'))
    return (hours * 60 + minutes) * 60 + (int(seconds) if dot else 0)
```

Example:

```
durations = map(to_seconds, ["25:01", "30:50.0"])
time_diff =  [end - start for start, end in zip(durations, durations[1:])]
# ->  [20940]
```